# css formating issue with html at top

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to design a webpage and was trying to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page at all times.  I did manage to do that with trouble but I figured out where my error was.  What I want to know is what is the difference between doing this,

```
body {
    background: red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background: black;
    padding:10px;
}
#content {
    background: green;
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

and doing this,

```
html,
body {
    background: red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background: black;
    padding:10px;
}
#content {
    background: green;
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Why does putting the html part at the top make the footer part of the code work?  It doesn't seem to effect any of the other code, just the part that makes the footer stay at the bottom.  This isn't my code just the code I got from here I have the same issue in my code though and was just wondering what the deal was cause I can't find anything on this.

http://www.cssreset.com/2010/css-tutorials/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Sorry if I wrote this wrong first time posting.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I was using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Body looks to its parent (HTML) for how to scale the dynamic property, so the HTML element needs to have it's height set as well.

Comment: I'll recommend to use min-height: 100% for both

Comment: But it works by just putting the "html," part of the css at the top.  Removing it causes it to break.  Just trying to figure out why as I haven't seen this in any CSS till I just now noticed it on this example code.

Answer (score 0):

the `absolute position` must be `relative` to another element and in your case the `footer` is relative to the `body`. By default the height of `body` and `html` isn't `100%` to the screen, so if you make your footer `absolute` to the bottom of body it will be at the bottom of body not the screen so to solve this you made the `body height` is `100%` of the html which must be also `100%` to the screen.

you can also use the `fixed position` instead of `absolute`, `position:fixed` will be `relative` to the `screen` not to any other `element` so you `footer` will be in the bottom even the body and html `height` isn't `100%`

Comment: Actually I have it working, I just need to know what, "html," means to css.  Cause removing that line causes the footer to break.  Thx for the explanation though still getting the hang of html, css, and javascript.